# How to change users in TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, authentication, svn, tortoisesvn

I was setting up another user to use our SVN repository.  He didn't have a username/password, so I logged in with my credentials.   We now have a username/password for him.

How do I get TortoiseSVN to logout and forget the old password so I can enter the new username/password?

Answer (score 467, accepted):

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. Right-click anywhere in the window.
3. Click **TortoiseSVN → Settings**.
4. Click **Saved Data**.
5. Click **Clear** beside **Authentication Data** (see below).
6. Check the authentication items to clear.
7. Click **OK**.

All saved Authentication Data for all projects is deleted.

You will have to re-enter credentials to reconnect.

[image: Clear Button]

Comment: I am using tortoise svn client on Windows 7. For my case in Saved Data tab, the Clear button for Authentication data is disable so deleting cache file solution worked for me well.

Comment: Thanks! Team Tortoise should bring this several layers up to surface as proper account management module for geeks.

Answer (score 48):

There are several ways to do it, through settings or by deleting the cache.

Deleting the cache is the most versatile method. First, locate it:

On XP, it was located here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USER%\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\
```

On Vista, it was located here:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\
```

Then look in those files with Notepad, and delete the one with your credentials.

Comment: %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\ should work everywhere (XP, Vista, 7)

Comment: In my case, I could not locate a file that described the realm in `svn.simple`. Instead, I found it in `svn.ssl.server`; by deleting it I had to accept the certificate, but surely enought was prompted for credentials.

Comment: I've just used this method, and it has worked without a hitch.

Comment: In my case cleaning the saved data did not help - TortoiseSVN asked me for username and password afterwards, and it saved and authenticated but kept putting in the log the previous user name. When I've deleted the file, actually renamed auth folder - all worked fine.

Comment: This is especially useful if you want to get your user name.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to remove only one saved password, e.g. for "user1":

- Go to the saved password directory (`*c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\*`)
- You will find several files in this folder (named with hash value)
- Find the file which contains the username "user1", which you want to change (open it with Notepad).
- Remove the file.
- Next time you will connect to your SVN server, Tortoise will prompt you for new username and password.

Answer (score 6):

When you use [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) (i.e., Active Directory Single Sign-On), you authenticate to AD resources automatically with your AD credentials. You've are already signed in to AD and these credentials are reused automatically. Therefore if your server is IWA-enabled (e.g., VisualSVN Server), the server does not ask you to enter username and password, passing `--username` and `--password` does not work, and the SVN client does not cache your credentials on disk, too.

When you want to change the user account that's used to contact the server, you need use the [Windows Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager) on client side. This is also helpful when your computer is not domain joined and you need to store your AD credentials to access your domain resources.

Follow these steps to save the user's domain credentials to Windows Credential Manager on the user's computer:

1. Start **Control Panel | Credential Manager** on the client computer.
2. Click **Add a Windows Credential**.
3. As **Internet or network address** enter the FQDN of the server machine (e.g., `svn.example.com`).
4. As **Username** enter your domain account's username in the `DOMAIN\Username` format.
5. Complete the password field and click **OK**.

Now when you will contact `https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo` or a similar URL, the client or web browser will use the credentials saved in the Credential Manager to authenticate to the server.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with this and trying all the answers on this page, I finally realized I had the incorrect credentials stored by windows for the server that hosts our subversion.  I cleared this stored value from windows credentials and all is well.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160614002053/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/remove-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials

Comment: Thank you @Patrick, you saved me the loss of several more hours of production loss. Indeed, I my credentials were being stored by Window's. Removing the stored credentials did the trick.

Answer (score -3):

Replace the line in htpasswd file:

Go to: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator-windows/

(If the link is expired, search another generator from google.com.)

Enter your username and password. The site will generate an encrypted line. Copy that line and replace it with the previous line in the file "repo/htpasswd".

You might also need to <kbd>Clear</kbd> the 'Authentication data' from TortoiseSVN → Settings → Saved Data.

Comment: Why should one change a line in any file on the server to remove the credentials on a local machine?