# How do I configure the username of a commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

My username (of myWindows account) is always shown as 'author' in the SVN repository log.

How can I configure SVN to use another name? Is there a way for Tortoise SVN, too?

And when I specify a username in the checkout command (--username), is that one used for commiting changed, too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153489/how-to-change-users-in-tortoisesvn could help here.

Comment: I've already read that but that's no my problem. His problem is the cached username, my one is that I don't want to transfer my real username. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Isn't that the point of a vcs? If you don't log the correct user ID you don't know who made the changes. `blame` wouldn't be correct. Your only option would be to configure SVN to use a dummy user ID.

Comment: You're right but I want to show another username than the name of my Windows account. It's like a forum for me, I just want to use a nickname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard SVN clients use a configuration file `.subversion\servers` where you can change many things regarding ahem... SVN-server related settings. In this file there is a `username` setting which can be set to different values for different repositories.

Where exactly this `servers` file is and how you can set stuff there is explained in *the book* here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers

Comment: Thanks! I set the username and cleared the cache but that didn't work! It only works fine if I checkout or commit the repo by `--username x`.